# kinetic js zindex

Tags: z-index, geometry, kineticjs

Can't quite figure out how to layer these objects with kenetic js, I want circle to be on top of circle2. Am I writing 'circle.setZIndex();' improperly? This is breaking the script.

jsfiddle with .setZIndex lines commented out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfuDs/

```
  function writeMessage(messageLayer, message) {
    var context = messageLayer.getContext();
    messageLayer.clear();
    context.font = '18pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
  }
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });
  var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var messageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 360,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 90,
    fill: 'orange',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });
circle2.setZIndex(3);

  var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 380,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 70,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });
   circle.setZIndex(2); 


  shapesLayer.add(circle);
  shapesLayer.add(circle2);

  stage.add(shapesLayer);
  stage.add(messageLayer);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add **circle2** shape first and then add **circle** shape second

```
shapesLayer.add(circle2);
shapesLayer.add(circle);
```

instead of

```
shapesLayer.add(circle);
shapesLayer.add(circle2);
```

Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/ZfuDs/1/

Comment: Thanks @Palani Kumar, that was easy. Although, I'd still like to know how to do it as I'll be adding a lot more shapes to this piece.

Comment: check out the kineticjs layering tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-shape-layering-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 3):

it appears that you can't call the z-index functions before the object is added to a layer I get:

```
TypeError: this.parent is undefined
    this.parent.children.splice(index, 1);
```

I don't get an error anymore, but the setZIndex() method doesn't seem to work even so, but 
circle.moveToTop() does work, check http://jsfiddle.net/ZfuDs/3

Comment: Thanks Brian, I think the previous answer works better as far as this solution—less code to just add the layers to the shape layer in the correct order. But using this will certainly help if interacting with other layers to bring this one out.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe we need to define the parent index and each child as well? Not sure how to approach that—after a lot of googling I've seen other issues with the z-index, just can't find good documentation how to incorporate.

Comment: the setZIndex() function doesn't seem to work as I'd expect anyway:

       circle2.setZIndex(2);
       circle.setZIndex(3);

works. but the lines swapped do not.

Comment: I was just fooling around with this some more, and using .getZindex() to print some debugging:

       circle.setZIndex(3);
       console.log(circle.getZIndex());   // 1        
       circle2.setZIndex(2);
       console.log(circle.getZIndex());   // 0   
       console.log(circle2.getZIndex());  // 1

maybe start numbering zIndex from 0 and stick with it?

Comment: @RooWM @Brian Mastrobuono Please keep in mind that Ive only just looked at KinectJS (like one minute ago;) but from what you guys have said, if you just want circle to be above circle2 then how about this `circle.setZIndex(circle2.getZIndex());` ... http://jsfiddle.net/ZfuDs/4/